# regex to match only alphanumeric, hyphen, underscore, and period, with no repeating punctuation

Tags: regex, string, typescript

I'm new to regex, and typescript, and trying to get a regex to match:

```
1. must start with alphanumeric (repeating is fine)
2. can contain alphanumeric (repeating is fine)
3. can contain periods, underscores, and/or hyphens (no repeating)
4. must end with alphanumeric (repeating is fine)
```

I've been searching, and found many examples that were kind of similar, and I tried to adjust them to work as I need, however I haven't been able to get to the correct solution. If anyone has a good regex to help and some explanation as to why's so I can learn more about the system that would be awesome.

Here are some examples of what I am trying to validate as acceptable strings:

```
this.is.Valid
also_a_valid_1
Me-too.im_an-ugly.but_vALid-5tring
```

and some examples of invalid strings that my current regex is allowing, but should fail because it has repeating periods/hyphens/underscores, and has period, hyphen, underscore at the start and end:

```
-this..should..not.be.valid....
..THIS__.-also-should..fail-
why..IS_regex--so.confusing-for-n0obs
```

and here is an example of the regex that I am using:

```
 validateString(myString: string): boolean {
    return (/^[a-zA-Z0-9_\-\.]+((\.-?|-\.?)[a-zA-Z0-9_\-\.]+)*$/.test(varKey))
 }
```

Comment: What do you mean by no duplicates? Did you mean to say no repeating chars?

Comment: i mean no repeating punctuations. i'll update the question to be more clear.

Comment: Basically, only one period, underscore, or hyphen is allowed but not at the end (what about the start)?

Comment: not allowed at the end or at the start

Comment: There seems to be also a requirement how a dot followed by a dash are ordered?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use:

```
^[a-z0-9]+(?:[._-][a-z0-9]+)*$
```

**Explanation:**

```
^                   # beginning of line
  [a-z0-9]+         # 1 or more alphanum
  (?:               # start non capture group
    [._-]           # period, underscore or hyphen
    [a-z0-9]+       # 1 or more alphanum
  )*                # end group, may appear 0 or more times
$
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/hcuSin/1)

```js
var test = [
    'this.is.Valid',
    'also_a_valid_1',
    'Me-too.im_an-ugly.but_vALid-5tring',
    '-this..should..not.be.valid....',
    '..THIS__.-also-should..fail-',
    'why..IS_regex--so.confusing-for-n0obs',
    'h',
    'sTrInG',
];
console.log(test.map(function (a) {
  return a+' :'+/^[a-z0-9]+(?:[._-][a-z0-9]+)*$/i.test(a);
}));
```

Comment: this is great! thank you. can you please explain what this part means? ?:

Comment: @llamacorn: I've added an explanation. You can found usefull info at the provided link

Comment: this is super helpful, thank you for the detailed explanation! i'm going to be doing a regex study sesh this weekend since it's so heavily used in the wild.

Comment: actually now that I am testing it outside of the demo playground, it doesn't work. it is saying false for string "h." and this should be valid. Also giving false for "sT"

Comment: sorry, i was being dumb and matching with each character as it was being typed, I moved the validation to the save.

Comment: @llamacorn: Don't forget to add the case insensitive flag `/.../i` see the code snippet

Comment: @Toto yea, you are good. I also missed the case-insensitive modifier on your demo. So, just remove those comments :)

Comment: @llamacorn: If it works for you, feel free to mark the answer as accepted, [How to accept an answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)

Comment: i requested an edit to include the case-insensitive modifier, was waiting for that. But I accepted the answer assuming that edit will get accepted :). Thanks for the reminder.